# r function: must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Im trying to create a function for my manager that quantifies the quality of the soil depending on their microorganisms. i would uploud the name of the different soils microbia species(here "a", "b",  "c"...) and then I would get an aproximation of the total quality. The final result depends on the type of the soil, and the EQR obtained. The function worked perfectly until I addded the "state" part, and when I run it now R says that those case_when "must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector".

```
sp<- c("a", "e", "d")
abund<-c(1.2, 0.8, 0.3)
comm<-as.data.frame(sp, abund)


soil_index <-function(comm, Type) {
  comm$score <- case_when(comm[,1]=="a" ~ 4, 
                               comm[,1]=="b" ~ 4,
                               comm[,1]=="c" ~ 4,
                               comm[,1]=="d" ~ 5, 
                               comm[,1]=="e"~ 3,
                               TRUE ~ NA_real_ )
                               
index <- sum(comm$score)
CR<- case_when(Type=="T01" ~ 4,
               Type=="T02" ~ 4.3,
               Type=="T03" ~ 5.1,
               Type=="T04" ~ 3.6,
               TRUE ~ NA_real_)
EQR<- index/CR

state<- case_when(Type=="T01" &EQR>= 0.79 ~ "Very good",
               Type=="T01" &EQR>=0.48 ~ "Good",
               Type=="T01" &EQR>=0.28 ~ "Moderate",
               Type=="T01" &EQR>=0.15 ~ "Bad",
               Type=="T01" &EQR<0.15  ~ " Very Bad",
               Type=="T02" &EQR>= 0.99 ~ "Very good",
               Type=="T02" &EQR>=0.78 ~ "Good",
               Type=="T02" &EQR>=0.48 ~ "Moderate",
               Type=="T02" &EQR>=0.35 ~ "Bad",
               Type=="T02" &EQR<0.35  ~ " Very Bad",
               Type=="T03" &EQR>= 0.73 ~ "Very good",
               Type=="T03" &EQR>=0.58 ~ "Good",
               Type=="T03" &EQR>=0.38 ~ "Moderate",
               Type=="T03" &EQR>=0.15 ~ "Bad",
               Type=="T03" &EQR<0.15  ~ " Very Bad",
               Type=="T04" &EQR>= 0.59 ~ "Very good",
               Type=="T04" &EQR>=0.48 ~ "Good",
               Type=="T04" &EQR>=0.18 ~ "Moderate",
               Type=="T04" &EQR>=0.05 ~ "Bad",
               Type=="T04" &EQR<0.05  ~ " Very Bad",
               TRUE~ "Error")
              
EQR<- index/CR
return(list(index = index, EQR = EQR, state=state))}

soil_index(comm, "T03")
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Works fine for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine on my computer:

```
>soil_index(comm,"T03)
$index
[1] 12

$EQR
[1] 2.352941

$state
[1] "Very good"
```

Did you try to rerun it or reopen R?

Comment: Hi! It must have been some problem with the copy paste because it does work perfectly now. Thank you.